# Error while querying Glue Catalog table using Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, amazon-athena, aws-glue, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a table in glue catalog which is created by glue crawler after parsing json files in s3. Now when I am querying this table using Athena, I am getting below error. Few things about this situation -

JSON files are in S3
Glue crawler created tables in glue catalog using json serder

table contains nested datatypes like array and struct
I am getting same error while querying other regular fields (excluding nested ones)
I am able to query same glue catalog table using Hive in EMR. Tried with and without nested datatypes and it works fine.

> Amazon Athena experienced a transient error while executing this
>   query. Waiting a couple of minutes and retrying the query may solve
>   the problem. If you continue to see the issue, please contact customer
>   support for further assistance. We apologize for the inconvenience.
>   You will not be charged for this query.

Comment: This might not be a solution, but you can try to validate your JSON or Glue table. Go to Athena and try to manually create the EXTERNAL Tables and Query it.

Comment: JSON Files and Glue schema is fine as I am able to query the same using HIVE. I haven't created a table in hive but referred to the one from glue catalog and I am able to query it. It's just that Athena is troubling and not giving a proper error message for me to check. Is there a way to check detailed athena logs?

Comment: Probably doesn't help, but if you check the error from the Query History tab on Athena, it might show a bit more.

Comment: Thank you Laurik, But the same error message is displayed on Query History table (no additional information)

Comment: AWS Support will be the best approach. The logs for Athena are not fully surfaced on the console. The AWS Support team have visibility. You will have to supply a query ID and the region that you ran the query in. Most common scenarios from my experience has been spaces or special characters inside the structs